how to get the live reactions in youtube live stream?
I need to get the live reaction and the like/dislike using the api only without any library. Using Node.js.
I am trying to get the live reactions and like/dislike from the end point of receiving a text message from the chat. The endpoint just fetches the text message.

Just to make sure may you precise what you mean precisely by live reactions?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@BenjaminLoison I mean the '100' 'love' etc. emojis in the live chat.

I have done tremendously progress about your issue but still have to verify on another YouTube channel account and to do so I have to wait 24 hours to have it verified. I will keep you tuned.

The following web-scraping Python script parametrized with CHANNEL_ID and VIDEO_ID prints the current reactions like:
[
    {
        "totalReactions": 2,
        "duration": {
            "seconds": "1"
        },
        "intensityScore": 0.75,
        "reactionsData": [
            {
                "unicodeEmojiId": "\ud83c\udf89",
                "reactionCount": 1
            },
            {
                "unicodeEmojiId": "\ud83d\ude04",
                "reactionCount": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "totalReactions": 1,
        "duration": {
            "seconds": "1"
        },
        "intensityScore": 0.75,
        "reactionsData": [
            {
                "unicodeEmojiId": "\u2764",
                "reactionCount": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "totalReactions": 0,
        "duration": {
            "seconds": "1"
        },
        "intensityScore": 1
    },
    {
        "totalReactions": 0,
        "duration": {
            "seconds": "1"
        },
        "intensityScore": 1
    },
    {
        "totalReactions": 0,
        "duration": {
            "seconds": "1"
        },
        "intensityScore": 1
    }
]

import requests
import json
import blackboxprotobuf
import base64
import time
from datetime import datetime

CHANNEL_ID = 'THE_CHANNEL_ID'
VIDEO_ID = 'THE_VIDEO_ID'

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/live_chat/get_live_chat'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

def getBase64Protobuf(message, typedef):
    data = blackboxprotobuf.encode_message(message, typedef)
    return base64.b64encode(data, altchars = b'-_')

message = {
    '1': {
        '5': {
            '1': CHANNEL_ID,
            '2': VIDEO_ID
        }
    },
    '4': 2,
}

typedef = {
    '1': {
        'type': 'message',
        'message_typedef': {
            '5': {
                'type': 'message',
                'message_typedef': {
                    '1': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    '2': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    }
                },
                'field_order': [
                    '1',
                    '2'
                ]
            }
        },
        'field_order': [
            '5'
        ]
    },
    '4': {
        'type': 'int'
    },
}

three = getBase64Protobuf(message, typedef)

message = {
    '119693434': {
        '3': three,
    }
}

typedef = {
    '119693434': {
        'type': 'message',
        'message_typedef': {
            '3': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            '20': {
                'type': 'int'
            },
        },
        'field_order': [
            '3',
            '20'
        ]
    }
}

json_ = {
    'context': {
        'client': {
            'clientName': 'WEB',
            'clientVersion': '2.20240509.00.00'
        }
    },
}
    
initialDatetime = datetime.now()
print(initialDatetime)
    
while True:
    message['119693434']['20'] = int((time.time() + 400) * 1_000_000)
    continuation = getBase64Protobuf(message, typedef)
    json_['continuation'] = continuation
    
    data = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json = json_).json()
    dataStr = json.dumps(data, indent = 4)
    if 'frameworkUpdates' in data:
        print(json.dumps(data['frameworkUpdates']['entityBatchUpdate']['mutations'][0]['payload']['emojiFountainDataEntity']['reactionBuckets'], indent = 4))
    isNeedleInData = 'invalidationContinuationData' in dataStr
    print(isNeedleInData, datetime.now() - initialDatetime)
    if not isNeedleInData:
        break
    time.sleep(10)

Here are notes about how I elaborated this script.
